# firebase security rules - public vs authenticated

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I hope it's the right forum to ask such a general question.

If I don't limit the read and write rules for authenticated users only, firebase states that anyone can read and write from the database. But how is it that anyone can read and write when the app itself decides whom to let read/write?

Is it because a hacker could theoretically hack into the database and read/write from the collections? If so, when the rules are limited for authenticated users only, an authenticated hacker could get to private data, for example content that is not in the scope of its user.

In short, how does it make any difference whether the rules are set to enable the public vs authenticated users access to the db, when in practice the developer is the one who determines these restrictions in the app, in the way the app communicates with firebase?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The app itself isn't the only source of traffic that your database could receive.  Your database exposes a REST API that anyone can call directly that effectively allows read and write access anywhere in the database that is not protected.  (Both Firestore or Realtime Database offer public REST APIs.) The only thing an attacker needs to know is the name of your project, and that string is effectively public after you first ship your app.

Also, the app could be compromised in such a way to let an attacker to do whatever they want in your app.  This type of compromise is fairly easy for web apps.  You shouldn't blindly assume that the user of your app isn't also modifying the way it works, as they essentially control the hardware that it's running on.

Comment: Thanks Doug, so in that case - for example in a social network app - what prevents an attacker who created a user (and hence he's authenticated) to read into other people's private messages?

Comment: Your security rules.

Comment: But security rules are general, they can for example determine that only authenticated users can read messages, but they cannot determine that only user A can read the messages of user B, and user C cannot. Or can they? Am I missing a bigger concept here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, they can, if you write them to be that way.  They have access to any document in your database, and you can use that to determine relationships between things.  Please study the documentation to find out everything you can do with security rules.  There are many pages to read here, including an API reference.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview